# How to get checkboxes result in Android

Tags: android, checkbox

i created checkboxes programmatically based on the no. of tasks in the database

for example: 3 tasks , 3 checkboxes

**LAYOUT**

No. of Tasks: 3

It will create this:

Task 1 [ ]

Task 2 [ ]

Task 3 [ ]

[Submit]

**OR**

for example: 5 tasks , 5 checkboxes

**LAYOUT**

No. of Tasks: 5

It will create this:

Task 1 [ ]

Task 2 [ ]

Task 3 [ ]

Task 4 [ ]

Task 5 [ ]

[Submit]

What i want is that when the user checks and submit, i want to know which tasks is checked. Like if task 3, and task 4 are checked and then submitted, the display message is task 3 and task 4 are checked.

**OR** task 1, task 2 and task 3 are checked and then submitted, the display message is task 1, task 2 and task 3 are checked. How to do that?

**UPDATED:**
Onclick method

```
cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                      if(cb.isChecked()){
                            list.add(task.getTaskId());
                            i++;
                         }

                    }

});
```

The array is empty. I dont know why. I put this condition cb.isChecked() so that only checked items is included in array.

Answer (score 1):

If the checkboxes have different ids you can use the id to determine the selected one. Otherwise you can give the checkbox a tag, using `setTag()` method. After the click you can call `checkbox.getTag()` and check which one it is.

UPDATE on comment:

If you are creating them by code you can give them generated ids. Add a resource id for each checkbox like this:

```
<item type="id" name="checkbox_task_1" />
```

Or the other approach, give them a tag. So when you create the checkbox code something like this:

```
checkbox.setTag("checkBox1");
```

You can use whatever object you want, e.g. an integer. And in your onClick method you should have something like this:

```
String tag = (String) checkbox.getTag();
if ("checkBox1".equals(tag)) {...}
```

SECOND UPDATE:

For creation of checkboxes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < userTasks.size(); i++) {
  ...
  checkBox.setTag(i);
}
```

In your onClick method:

```
int tag = (Integer) checkbox.getTag();
if (tag == 1) {...}
```

NEXT UPDATE - onClick

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
  if(cb.isChecked()) {
    list.add((Integer) cb.getTag());
  }
}
```

Comment: but i cant determine the id. i created the checkboxes programmatically based on the no. of tasks.

Comment: what if you dont know how many number of tasks the user will input? do i have to make like a 1000 item ids just to be sure?

Comment: cause the no. of tasks is based on the user input

Comment: Are you creating them in a loop? Then you can use the index as tag.

Comment: confused. how to know if a checkbox is checked or not? for example, a checkbox with tag 12, how to know if its checked or not?

Comment: On each checkbox you need to register an onclick listener.

Comment: please check my updated , It wont work. I put the onclick method.